# WKURLSchemeHandler and FormData

Tags: ios, webkit, wkurlschemehandler

I develop hybrid application.

When JS send XMLHTTPRequest with FormData, App WKURLSchemeHandler custom class receives WKURLSchemeTask with request, but request has no HTTPBody or HTTPBodyStream. Both properties has value nil.

Does anyone know, whether or not WKURLSchemeHandler supports FormData as request body?

Comment: In case someone wondering why multipart request lacks HTTPBody or HTTPBodyStream. Issue is about Blob/File objects created in JS. Files from photo gallery works good.

Comment: What does that mean?